# HTML events pop up in same time, how to just pick one

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I make a page write like this:

```
<div id=“listener”>
   <ul id="top">
    <li id="li-QD">
      <input id="inV-QD" type="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input id="inC-QD" data-coor="3" data-level="0" data-order="0" data-parent="top" type="checkbox">
        <span></span>
      </label>
      <label for="inV-QD">QD</label>
          <ul id="ul-QD">
             <li id="li-southPart">
                <input id="inV-southPart" type="checkbox">
                <label>
                <input id="inC-southPart" data-coor="0" data-level="1" data-order="0" data-parent="QD" type="checkbox">
                <span></span>
                </label>
                <label for="inV-southPart">southPart</label>            
             </li>
          </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is a list added dynamic.
And I add event listener to “div” at top, so whenever I click one input,I will find out who was clicked by using “even.target”, getting target-name.

Now, because I'm using “span”, so when I clicked, two events will pop up. I thought I will tell two events by using `event[0],event[1`], but it turns out the event is an object. (The “event” is eventlistener binding function’s parameter function(event) ). I can’t treat it as array.

```
function bodyIni(){
let httpRequest;
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
const url = "http://localhost/mapMonitor/areaIni.php";
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;

httpRequest.open("GET",url,true);
httpRequest.send();

function alertContents(){
    if(httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
        if(httpRequest.status ===200){
            //alert(httpRequest.responseText);Add innetHTML
            document.getElementById("dym-List").innerHTML=httpRequest.responseText;
            //stopPropagation <span> $$ <label[for]>
            const spans = document.querySelectorAll("#listener span")
            for(let index=0;index<spans.length; index++){
                spans[index].addEventListener("click",function(e){e.stopPropagation();},false);
            }

            const labelFors = document.querySelectorAll("#listener label[for]")
            for( index=0;index<labelFors.length; index++){
                labelFors[index].addEventListener("click",function(e){e.stopPropagation();},false);
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("this is the wrong part.");
        }
    }
}//End of Dym-adding part

// add listener to "#dym-List"list
const list = document.getElementById("listener");
list.addEventListener("click",getElementUsingId,false);
}
```

And I using this function pick up the input checkbox.

```
    function getElementUsingId(event){
        let tarname = event.target;
        let nameId = tarname.id;
        let index = nameId.indexOf("-")+1;
        //get the district Name
        let name = nameId.substring(index);
        //store select name.
        selectName = name;
        //get the name ,with prefix, we can call associate functions;
        const liNameID = "#li-"+name;
        uncheckAllBox();
        checkAllChildBox(liNameID);
        const inCName = "inC-"+name;
        showArea(inCName);
        //showMap(name);
    }
```

My way is using `document.querySelect()` find all the spans, and using `event.stopPropagation()` to every span. I think that is no good.

You can see in the last function, if I don’t stop “span” and `label[for]`, I will get two events at same time. And `event.target` will give two outputs, which is two objects, not in one array .So can I separate two events by using an array-like way?

Comment: You can't use curly quotes around HTML attributes, they have to be ordinary ASCII single or double quotes.

Comment: You get multiple events because of bubbling. First the event fires on the inner element, when the listener returns it fires on the next element, and so on. There's no array because they aren't really at the same time.

Comment: This is re-editing in iPad, quotes are ok in origin,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process the event on the spans, you can do something like:

```
if (event.target.tagName == "SPAN") {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // rest of event processing
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot.this is working .and Without so many listeners,perfect.